# How to combine min-width, fit-conent and absolute width?

Tags: html, css

I have flex container with two children elements. Those elemenets have set `overflow-x` to `hidden` + `text-overflow` to `ellipsis` to ensure that larger texts will be truncated.

I want to set the rule for their width which ensures me that the minimum width for those children will be either fixed size like `100px` for larger texts. Or if the text itself is smaller than `100px`, use `fit-content` (or another equivalent).

I have tried following:

```css
.blue {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}  

.blue > .red {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px red solid; 
  padding: 10px;
}  

.blue > .red.second {
  min-width: 100px;
  /* min-width: fit-content; */
  /* min-width: min(fit-content, 5rem); */
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="red first">
    Some little bit longer text as an example
  </div>
  <div class="red second">
    Another shorter example
  </div>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <div class="red first">
    Short text
  </div>
  <div class="red second">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/arakasi/s15a7pjg/5/ for another testing snippet.

Is it possible to combine `fit-content` and `100px` into one rule for min-width to consider only the smaller one?

Comment: Maybe `clamp()` can help you here. Alternatively, you have to use JS as CSS does not check the computed width of an element.

Comment: I would say that `clamp` function has differrent purpose

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `max-width: 100px`

```js
let blues = document.querySelectorAll(".blue");
let reds = document.querySelectorAll(".red");
let blueView = document.querySelector("#blue_width");
let redView = document.querySelector("#red_width");

/* debugger */
;

document.querySelector("input").oninput = function() {
  blueView.textContent = this.value;
  blues.forEach((element) => element.style.width = this.value + "px");
  let offsets = [];
  reds.forEach((element) => offsets.push(element.offsetWidth));
  redView.textContent = offsets;
};

document.querySelector("input").oninput();
```

```css
.blue {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.red {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="red first">
    Some little bit longer text as an example
  </div>
  <div class="red second">
    Another shorter example
  </div>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <div class="red first">
    Short text
  </div>
  <div class="red second">
    text
  </div>
</div>

Red box's width is <span id="red_width"></span> px
<br><br> Blue box's width is
<input type="range" value="600" min="100" max="600">
<span id="blue_width"></span> px
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, that `max-width` is not a way forward. It does not follow the use-case I have presented.

Comment: @JanStanicek it does. Your item will either have a width equal to 100px (long text) or it will fit the content

Comment: As I have written I need to set `min-width` instead of `max-width`. You are describing different usecase. I want to show entire text if there is enough space. See the example for more explanation.